# Is there an up-to-date version of the AlchemiAPI for C#?

Tags: c#, alchemyapi

When compiling the current Alchemi API for C# I get the following messages:

```
AlchemyAPI.cs(670,16): warning CS0618: 'System.Net.GlobalProxySelection' is obsolete: 'This class has been deprecated.
        Please use WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy instead to access and set the global default proxy. Use 'null' instead of
        GetEmptyWebProxy. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'
AlchemyAPI.cs(681,16): warning CS0618: 'System.Net.GlobalProxySelection' is obsolete: 'This class has been deprecated.
        Please use WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy instead to access and set the global default proxy. Use 'null' instead of
        GetEmptyWebProxy. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'
```

which lead me to believe that maybe the api may be outdated. Is there an up-to-date api somewhere?

Comment: The examples (with the exception of one, and that might be an unrelated issue) seem to run just fine.  I'm wondering this myself, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A community member recently forked the [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/) C# SDK, and you can access it on [GitHub.](https://github.com/martindevans/AlchemyApiSharp). That is the most up-to-date version currently available.